# How to find when I upgraded node on ubuntu?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I upgraded node from v8.x to v10.x a couple of weeks ago.

My bash history does not have timestamp enabled so I cannot tell on which date I upgraded.

Is it possible to look at any log files to get this info?

Comment: did you look in /var/log ?

Comment: you could look at the modification date of your node executable file (or maybe even at the modification date of the simlink in /bin or /usr/bin or so, locations just guesses, not using ubuntu at the moment, but you can find it with `which node`)

Answer (score 1):

You should have rsyslog and auditd setup if you need this level of accounting. Look at the time stamps on the files, and you may see a date that matches when you installed the package. Or look to see if their is a cache directory for the tool you used to update it with etc..